# Cannot update apt-get due to 404 error

Tags: 14.04, apt

I got errors on update apt-get

```
$ apt-get update
[...]                        
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
  404  Not Found
[...]
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/clicompanion-devs/clicompanion-nightlies/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages 404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I've read several forum topics about fixes but there is anyone works.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists)

Comment: have you added the PPA yourself? then I suggest checking if the PPA URL is correct

Comment: Thanks for this link. It's almost what I need. I've posted the solution which could help me.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it with a bit different way but not as in [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists).
I don't know how to solve it in command line but I did it in UI.

1. Open `update-manager`.
2. After checking go to `Settings... > Other Software`.
3. Uncheck all matched with link http://ppa.launchpad.net/clicompanion-devs/clicompanion-nightlies/ubuntu

For now `apt-get update` works fine.